# JSoup Getting Image Google Play Listing?

Tags: android, jsoup

I am attempting to get the Header Image of a Google Play App by Using the Jsoup Library. Here is the Code:

```
public static String getGooglePlayURL(String urlP) {
    // LOAD IMAGE URL
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tbs.search&hl=en").get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String imageUrlAct = "";
    if (doc != null) {
        Element image = doc.select("img").first();
        imageUrlAct = image.attr("abs:src");
    }
    Log.e("URL GP", "URL: " + imageUrlAct);
    return imageUrlAct;
}
```

However it seems to return an Empty String every time. What am I doing wrong or what are the alternatives? 
Thank you very Much.

Comment: Which is the empty string here? `imageUrlAct`? It seems working fine.. Did you check your network connection?

Comment: Yeah imageUrlAct is always empty.

Comment: I tried, its working, I get `https://lh5.ggpht.com/QhSfjfFnFqaKISt5gq4_Cy8lXwlLoKfZmh783ByZA2xC-LU1wfocG5gF1vintWLXWZxt=w300` when I print `imageUrlAct`.

Comment: Might be my Connection then.

Comment: Strange thats not an Image URL though.